# How to configure Nginx to serve a variety of back-ends via multiple FCGI processes?

Tags: php, nginx, python, fastcgi, perl

I've seen a lot of tutorials showing one how to set up **PHP/Python/Perl/RoR** on nginx via various FCGI processes.

None of the tutorials that I found show one how to serve multiple FCGI services off one server.

How would one configure the stable nginx (nginx-0.7.64) to serve multiple FCGI processes (one for each of the above languages)?

Example addresses for each FCGI process are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1:8080 - PHP
127.0.0.1:8081 - Python
127.0.0.1:8082 - Perl
127.0.0.1:8083 - Ruby on Rails
```

An example configuration file that shows one how to implement multiple FCGI's off one server is really what I need. Perhaps others will benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
location /
{
FCGI..PARAMETERS (find on the web)
}
```

To:

```
location /python/

{
python FCGI..PARAMETERS (find on the web)
}

location /php/
{
php FCGI..PARAMETERS (find on the web)
}

location /perl/
{
perl FCGI..PARAMETERS (find on the web) - although nginx supports it embedded.
}

location /ror/
{
ror FCGI..PARAMETERS (find on the web)
}
```

Make the above folders, python/php/perl/ror under /var/www/nginx-default/ -> each will be served by a different FCGI process as per your FCGI configuration -> just place the files that need to be executed in their an run the fcgi process + restart nginx.